# Editing/Updating multiple objects at a time on a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to be able to edit / update multiple objects at a time, i.e. a page to render an email field for all users.

The standard approach doesn't work:

- `form_for` requires a single object with an `id`
- a `:put` request to the `user_path` also requires an `id` parameter

How can I generate a form to update multiple users? I want to use only the built-in Rails form, not a third-party one.

Comment: One option is to create an ActiveModel "form object" which is submitted to a controller which validates the form and then updates various models. Another might be "nested attributes", although in my experience using nested attributes never works out too well.

Answer (score 2):

Create a form_for to a new endpoint (not the default PUT one), you are not updating 1 resource, that endpoint makes nonsense to be used.

PUT /resource/bulk (for example)

html (i haven't tested this it is just a scheme):

```
form_tag '/resource/bulk', method: :put do
  @resources.each do |resource|
    text_field_tag("#{resource.id}[email]")
  end
end
```

action:

```
#params => { 1 => { "email" => "foo@foo.com" }, 2 => { "email" => "bar@bar.com" } }
def bulk
  resources = params[:form]
  Resource.update(resources.keys, resources.values)
end
```

this is just a schema of a valid solution, I don't have any Rails app or irb right now to test this solution.